# OpeneERP: How to create a button with no icon (only text on it)

Tags: button, odoo, openerp-7

I would like to create a button with no icon, only a text that i display.
I 've tried to not put 'icon' parameter but it doesn't work.

Here's the code i've wrote:

```
<button name="open_popup" string="Quantités produites" type="object"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've known a possibility, but i think that was a listview bug in chrome or something.

maybe you should try class="oe_link" on your button, so it looks like a link.

```
<button name="open_popup" string="Quantités produites"
 type="object" class="oe_link"/>
```

Comment: I don't know why (I've already posted this issue,see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299513/openerp-css-class-not-recognized) but i can't  get a way to use css classes in my XML files.it gave me the error "Invalid XML for View Architecture".
Is there any other way to do this without using css classes?
Thank you for your help

Comment: have you tried to add version="7.0" to your form-tag? this will allow some new attributes on some tags.

Comment: Yeees, it worked when i tried it on a form.Thank you sooo much. unfortunately,i have my button in a tree view,when i tried to put the version tag it gave me error

Comment: it should work with tree views, too. just create a new question and i will look into it :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but i guess there is some bugs using css class in chrome browser.I've tried to open it in IE and the text is well displayed.thank you again for your help :) (for the error, i just had to restart the server)

Answer (score 0):

In version 7 you can use class="oe_link":

```
<button name="open_popup" string="Quantités produites" type="object" class="oe_link"/>
```